# nonce in World State

Tags: nonce, yellow-paper

Is the nonce stored in the Ethereum world state explicitly? Acco. to the yellow paper it does.
But in "Mastering Ethereum", Andreas writes -

> However, the nonce is not stored explicitly as part of an account’s state on the blockchain. Instead, it is calculated dynamically, by counting the number of confirmed
> transactions that have originated from an address.

Which one is the case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are talking about the *transaction nonce*, and not the nonce which is related to the mining algorithm.

From the blockchain's point of view the "world state" is only a series of transactions (inside blocks). So there is no "current" state stored anywhere, only transactions which are executed in sequence. As the nonce is part of the transactions, the nonce is not stored anywhere explicitly.

However, nodes / clients can build various data structures on top of the transactions. They use the transactions as building blocks but they may store extra data on top of that, such as a concept "current state" or "history state". In this sense you may consider the nonce to be stored explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. Got the nonce bit. But, isn't the stateTrie stored on the blockchain itself?

Comment: Hmm, a fair point. Now that I'm reading the block contents again, to be honest, I don't really understand how it works. https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/11/15/merkling-in-ethereum/